# Laravel yield is empty

Tags: php, laravel

I have a master blade file that includes some other blade files and yields content of a blade file called `home` which I extend on this `master` blade, I can click on `master` from my `home` blade in phpstorm and it takes me to the correct file, so they must be connected correctly.

The problem is the contents are not loaded, it just loads the head/header and footer but nothing from my home.blade.

My master.blade.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
@include('partials.head')
<body>

@include('partials.header')
@yield('content')
@include('partials.footer')
</body>
</html>
```

In my home.blade.php

```
@extends('master')
@section('title', 'Home')
@section('content')
<main id="content">
    test
</main>
@endsection
```

It loads everything correctly except the `content` section. What am I doing wrong?

Only route I got:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('master');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change the view of the route,

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});
```